# Java process halts before GC

Tags: java, process, jvm, hbase, cpu

We're running HBase HMaster process in production environment. Normally there're so many logs in the log file. But for a specific periodic, nothing is recorded and we think the gc occurs. As expected, gc occurred at that time but not for the whole period.

For example, the gc start from 32:24 and last 25.53 seconds. But I don't get any log from 32:06 to 32:49. I'm wondering what happened before the gc. It seemed to "stop the world" as well.

I'm sure the HMaster wrote logs if its process is running. Is it something about CPU time? How can I figure it out?

Comment: @shekharsuman: where is it mentioned system.gc?

Comment: @Nazgul-Sorry, simply `garbage collector`!

Comment: @tobe: is it a consistent pattern? Every time you see a halt in logs, you find an appropriate pause in the GC logs and then a few seconds of blackout? I wont worry about a few seconds of blackouts based on log writing activity. Better would be to monitor the instance and see if there are threads blocked.

Comment: @Nazgul Yes, it's consistent. The HMaster will print out the gc times after each gc and they're consistent with those in gc log. The gc log is generated by jvm so I think it's reliable.

Comment: How big is your heap size? sometimes generations are resized after collections and if you dont set a fixed generation size resizing may take some time to finish.

Comment: @Nazgul Here's my configuration: -Xmx10240m -Xmn1024m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m.

Comment: And the gc log looks like this: 2014-08-25T22:32:24.399+0800: 3014.801: [GC 3015.135: [ParNew: 917504K->131072K(917504K), 25.1790250 secs] 8505449K->7857704K(10354688K), 25.5234650 secs] [Times: user=100.69 sys=0.23, real=25.53 secs]
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 25.6863560 seconds

Comment: No gc log from 22:32:06 to 22:32:24, But my Java process seemed stopped and not responsed to its clients.

Comment: add the newsize and maxnewsize parameters to JVM. kepp both valuesa same to prevent them from resizing and check again. Also use a CMS colelctor. check the answer for a sample jvm settings to get u started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this:

`-server -d64 -Xms10240m -Xmx10240m -XX:PermSize=512M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:NewSize=5120m -XX:MaxNewSize=5120m -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:SurvivorRatio=20 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC  -XX:+OptimizeStringConcat -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8 -XX:ConcGCThreads=8 -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=80 -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath="${bundled.server.access.log}" -Xloggc:"${bundled.server.access.log}"/java_gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution`

This settings makes your eden space + survivors = 5GB and old gen = 5GB.
Drop the MaxDirectMemorySize parameter as JVM automatically scales the direct mem buffer

Comment: MaxDirectMemorySize is useful for HBase because we use [BucketCache](http://hortonworks.com/blog/hbase-blockcache-101/) to allocate cached data or index. 

Anyway, thanks for replying. This is accidental and I can't repro after that. Maybe not related to gc.